# trying to reference config file in different project

Tags: c#

My test file is in the project at the following folder:

```
C:\path1\path2\path3\path4\Tests\Unit\MyUnitTest.cs
```

My config file is in the project in the following folder:

```
C:\path1\path2\Web\configs\myprecious.config
```

How do I reference my config file in the MyUnitTest.cs file as a relative path? Currently I am hardcoding it as `C:\path1\path2\Web\configs\myprecious.config` which is not correct.

Please let me know.

Thanks..

**EDIT**:

I solved it by reference it as follows:

Web\configs\myprecious.config

Comment: There's a way of linking a file in different project within a solution... I'm familiar with that actual clickings, though.

Comment: Remember to 'answer this question' when you can

Comment: thanks.. i forgot about that. Just added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reference it as follows:

Web\configs\myprecious.config